# How to check if curl ftp upload successful in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, curl, ftp

I using the following command to upload the file to an FTP server:

```
curl -v -k --ftp-ssl --ftp-pasv --user xxxxx:yyyyy ftp://x.x.x.x:77/TEST/ -T D:TESTING.zip
```

The main problem is I don't know how to check if the file is successfully uploaded to the FTP server. If its connection fail or upload processing fail, 
how could I can check this situation in Windows bat file? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Check `curl` exit code

```
curl -v -k --ftp-ssl --ftp-pasv --user user:pass ftp://example.com/path/ -T test.zip
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Error
) else (
    echo Success
)
```

Comment: This is quite useful, and I also can use errorlevel to check the exit status, thanks a lot.